# Why do different calls to this function sometimes take the exact same time?

Tags: python

I create a function in the python repl (having already imported 'time'):

```
def a():
    t = time.time()
    s = [False for x in xrange(1000000)]
    print time.time()-t
```

On this machine (64 bit Windows 7, Python 2.7.x), I test running this function over and over, by repeatedly pressing [up arrow],[enter] just for fun. Or for seeing run durations. It seems to oscillate between something like 0.08s and 0.18s.

But then something weird happened:

```
>>> a()
0.140000104904
>>> a()
0.138000011444
>>> a()
0.077999830246
>>> a()
0.138000011444
```

It could make some sort of sense to me, maybe, if two consecutive runs gave the exact same time. But for two calls with an intermediate run? What's going on here?

Comment: Why it should be weird?

Comment: You can't really trust the results when timing functions in this way. The times may be skewed by other processes demanding time on your CPU. Better to use `timeit.timeit()` which runs the function multiple times, disables garbage collection, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be sure to use the timeit module from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timing things by just taking the difference of before and after timestamps can be sensitive to other things going on on your system. The recommended way to time things is with the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html) module, which does its best to control for those sensitivities.

Comment: So maybe it's just Windows caching the calls somehow, and the answer to the why lies outside of the scope of Python? (The answer of "what to do" definitely seems to be timeit).

Comment: More likely, you're seeing differences in what the process scheduler decides to do - it might schedule, say, your browser doing a GUI redraw for some fraction of a second before it runs Python. That would mean that the *lower* timings are closer to being accurate. But there can be some variability in Python's own speed too. This is why the recommended usage of `timeit`s Python API (and how its command line API works) is to take the average over a large number of runs (defaulting to a million), and to do *that* several times (default 3) and take the best.